# Splat operator and method overriding

Tags: ruby, overriding, splat

I have a base class with child classes that override a method that takes multiple arguments.

```
class Parent
  def foo *bar
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def foo bar, baz
  end
end
```

This works fine. However, suppose there is a method foobar in Parent that calls foo:

```
def foobar *foo_args
  foo foo_args
end
```

This raises a ArgumentError when called on a Child instance because foo_args is one single array, while Child.new.foo expects two objects. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Your code works fine for me in Ruby 2.1 and 1.8.7. As far as I know, you're wrong about method signatures having to match between parents and children. There is no such requirement in Ruby. This works fine: http://pastebin.com/g5VgzKPX

Comment: Exactly - in Ruby it's just a matter of run-time message dispatching.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Correct, I was wrong about the signature. However, calling the method from the parent is still an issue. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but I think this may be what you want:

```
def foobar *foo_args
  foo(*foo_args)
end
```

Still, `Child.new.foo` must take exactly two arguments for it to not raise an error.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I just need to "unsplat" the argument. Thank you.